# How can I collect data on authenticated versus anonymous traffic?

Tags: 7, performance

One of the important metrics I miss while planning for performance optimization is the type of traffic my site is receiving. What are the ways for collecting data about the type of traffic? I am mostly interested in anonymous versus authenticated requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [google analytics](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module does this out of the box.

Comment: In the settings you can just segment by role(s) (i.e. anonymous vs. authenticated).

Comment: You mean analytics dashboard or drupal GA module?

Comment: If you install the drupal GA module, segment by role and then look at the google analytics dashboard it should show you.

Comment: +1 GA is a great module, it even handles download of files such as .mp3 and .m3u streams - useful for gathering some listener statistics if you run a radio station website based on drupal.